# JBoss EAP 6.x on Java 8

Tags: java, jboss7.x

Anyone know when Redhat will start supporting JDK 8 for the JBoss EAP 6 line? Java 8 has been in the wild for over 6 months now. I am migrating a JBoss 5 application and would like to move to the latest version of Java at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Quite a bit late with answering, but:

RedHat just released EAP 6.4, which officially supports Java 8.

Best,
Alex